# How to add array items in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In a wordpress plugin, there is a field box called 'data' where I can add code for it to pull, below in the code where it says 'data =' that is me referencing the box. In the box:

What I put in the field box entitled 'data':

```
{
  contacts: [
    { name: "Name 1", email: "email1@test.com" },
    { name: "Name 2", email: "email2@test.com" }
  ]
};
```

This is what I put in the global field box, for it to apply to everything.

```
function (jQueryPopoverObj, mapObject, mapsvgInstance) {

  // "this" = clicked mapObject
  if(this.mapsvg_type == "region"){
    return '<b>'+this.id+'</b>' +
      this.data.contacts.map(function(contact) {
        return contact.name + '<br>' +
          '<a href="mailto:'+contact.email+ '">' + contact.email + '</a>'
         }).join('<br>');

  } else if (this.mapsvg_type == "marker"){
    return 'Marker - <b>'+this.id+'</b>, contact: '+this.data.email;
 }

}
```

I want to also add { seat: "County Seat"} to the data portion and add it in the function. 
I tried adding a line in the contacts, and then adding `+ '<br>' + contact.seat`, after return contact.name, with no luck. Basically when it does the popover (which it pulls from global function for the template and the information from the data field box), I want it to have the CountySeat under the County Name (e.g. the County Seat for Harris County is Houston, so it would have Houston under Harris County).

[Example of Lubbock County without the City name under it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ummT5.jpg)

Comment: You have a `data` object, which contains an array. I follow that much.  Then you are trying to add `{ seat: "County Seat"}` to that object/array --- somehow.  The thing you are trying to say isn't in your code *anywhere*.  Not to be rude, but you *really* should read some basic documentation on how objects and arrays work.

Comment: Thank you. The data object comes from a form field of a wordpress plugin so I can't change that. And I am limited to that field box entitled 'data', so I have to add everything under data.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
           contacts: [
                     { name: "Name 1", email: "email1@test.com" },
                     { name: "Name 2", email: "email2@test.com" }
                     ]
           }
```

To add a new property seat you can simply do this-

```
data["seat"] = "County Seat"
```

or

```
data.seat = "County Seat"
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1bxke8g6/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. The data object comes from a form field of a wordpress plugin so I can't change that. And I am limited to that field box entitled 'data', so I have to add everything under data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to set the seat assignment on the contact?  You'd have to get the contact from the array, looping through each one and figuring out the one you want to use, then do contact.seat = "XYZ", which will add a seat property to the contact object.  You can then use contact.seat in the string output but you have to null check it because it may be null.  To help with that, I'd recommend defaulting it to an empty string like:

```
 data = {
contacts: [
 { name: "Name 1", email: "email1@test.com", seat: "" },
 { name: "Name 2", email: "email2@test.com", seat: "" }
  ]
}
```

And then change it when it is assigned.